# why does the stream not recognize my type?

Tags: java, filter, lambda, java-8, java-stream

```
public class ActivityInventoryMem<Activity> extends TreeSet<Activity> implements ActivityInventory<Activity> {

  @Override
  public ToDo toDo( LocalDate date ) {
    Stream<Activity> s = this.parallelStream();

    s.filter( a ->  a.completed() );
    return new ToDo();
  }
}
```

Here's the exception

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: java.util.stream.Stream.filter
at com.lm.infrastructure.memory.ActivityInventoryMem.toDo(ActivityInventoryMem.java:16)
at com.lm.infrastructure.memory.ActivityInventoryMemNGTest.testToDo(ActivityInventoryMemNGTest.java:46)
```

I'm running it in jdk 8, and I put the following in my `pom.xml`, which it now seems to recognize the lambda's

```
    <!-- maven-compiler-plugin -->
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
```

The problem (from what I've gathered from netbeans) is that it's treating `a` as just an `Object` not an `Activity` and so it can't see `.completed()`, how can I fix this?

Comment: I don't know if this is your complete code, but if it is, the `s.filter()` call effectively does nothing. This is a lazy, intermediate operation. The stream won't actually do anything until you add a terminal operation. See the `java.util.stream` class documentation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your declaration:

```
public class ActivityInventoryMem<Activity> extends TreeSet<Activity> implements ActivityInventory<Activity>
//                                 ^ (1)                     ^ (2)                                  ^ (3)
```

the uses of `Activity` at (2) and (3) are as type arguments to `TreeSet` and `ActivityInventory`, whereas the use at (1) is declaring a **new type parameter** for your `ActivityInventoryMem` class. Thus, uses of the symbol `Activity` within that class don't refer to your actual `Activity` class, they refer to some type parameter whose actual type is unknown.

You probably just want to leave off (1) from your class declaration:

```
public class ActivityInventoryMem extends TreeSet<Activity> implements ActivityInventory<Activity>
```